# I'm looking to pull specific content from another website using php and load it into an iframe on my website

Tags: php, iframe

In particular I'm only looking for the the content that is loaded within a couple divs.

Should i use cURL?

I'm aware of this:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

but not sure how to pull div classes and id's.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://anywhoyp.yellowpages.com/whitepages");

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
```

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

Comment: Maybe I am misuderstanding the question, but an `iframe` has a `src` attribute, cant you just fill that?

Comment: I don't want the whole page. Just a few divs from the page. Hope that helps to clear up the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, file_get_contents will get you the full page source, which is not needed. So, you have to use a DOM parser afterwards to extract what you need. The problem is that PHPs DOM parsers are sloooooooooow. In https://github.com/msmuenchen/wiki-staticdumps/blob/master/scripts/process.php I used ganon library to modify DOM - you should be able to figure out how to make it suit your needs from this sourcecode.

Comment: Also, you might want to use a cronjob or at least caching for the job (just write the content you extracted into a file and only re-load the content when the file is older than 5 minutes), because the HTTP request takes time and the processing even more.

Comment: I'm still looking at that but i'm a bit confused.